# Is there a way to run multi-SQLs by RMySQL(dbExecute)?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am using RMySQL to connect and manipulate MySQL.
Now I have a SQL like:
"drop table if exists t_tmp; create table t_tmp(name varchar(20));"
which works just fine in MySQL CLI.

But when I put these SQLs to RMySQL.dbExecute() exception throws:
"could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table t_tmp(name varchar(20))' at line 1"

I am trying to run the 2 SQLs respectively, then they both work out OK.

Is there any way I can put the whole STRING(SQLs) and run it correctly in RMySQL?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot run two back-to-back `dbExecute()` calls?

Comment: thanks for reply, Parfait. I am worrying about the performance.

Comment: For those two commands? Give it a try and see.

Comment: yep，now I run dbExecute for each SQL. The SQLs above are samples, in practice the number of SQLs are much more than 2. thanks:)